# Retrieve latent factors from pyspark matrix factorization model

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, collaborative-filtering

Newbie to Spark and PySpark.

I am following the collaborative filtering tutorial [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-collaborative-filtering.html).

I was able to train the model. However, I don't know how to access the latent factors (vectors) corresponding to users and products.

Reproducing the top part of the code from the above link here:

```
from pyspark.mllib.recommendation import ALS, MatrixFactorizationModel, Rating

# Load and parse the data
data = sc.textFile("data/mllib/als/test.data")
ratings = data.map(lambda l: l.split(','))\
    .map(lambda l: Rating(int(l[0]), int(l[1]), float(l[2])))

# Build the recommendation model using Alternating Least Squares
rank = 10
numIterations = 10
model = ALS.train(ratings, rank, numIterations)
```

How can I extract the latent factors from `model`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
model.productFeatures()
```

and

```
model.productFeatures()
```

Comment: I have another question. Using `spark-shell`, I can access files in HDFS by `val myfile = sc.textFile("/user/myname/path/to/file/myfile.txt")`. However, if I do this in `PySpark` (like `myfile = sc.textFile("/user/myname/path/to/file/myfile.txt")`, it complains that this directory does not exist. Even if I specify the path as `hdfs:///user/myname/path/to/file/myfile.txt`, it is unable to load the file. Any suggestions on what else I can try?